# Traefik v2 [how to route to specific port]

Tags: docker, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm trying to start the change of backends to be compatible with traefik v2.0.

The old configuration was:

```
  labels:
    - traefik.port=8500
    - traefik.docker.network=proxy
    - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:consul.{DOMAIN}
```

I assumed, the network is not necessary anymore, it would change the new traefik for:

```
    - traefik.http.routers.consul-server-bootstrap.rule=Host('consul.scoob.thrust.com.br')
```

But how I set, that this should forward to my backend at port 8500? and not 80 where the entrypoint was reached at Traefik?

My goal would try to accomplish something like this:
https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster-docker-consul/#migrate-configuration-to-consul

Is it still possible?
I saw, there was no --consul or storeconfig command in v2.0

Answer (score 27):

You need `traefik.http.services.{SERVICE}.loadbalancer.server.port`

```
  labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.{SERVICE}.loadbalancer.server.port=8500"
    - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    - "traefik.http.routers.{SERVICE}.rule=Host(`{DOMAIN}`)"
```

- Replace `{SERVICE}` with the name of your service.
- Replace `{DOMAIN}` with your domain name.

If you want to remove the proxy network you'll need to look at https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/providers/docker/#usebindportip

Comment: What if I have multiple instances of an application, their ports are dynamic, how can traefik read those ports?